# What semantics should be used when referring to waterfall and agile methodologies

Tags: agile, scrum, development-methodologies, methodology, waterfall

I've just been involved in a debate regarding semantics of how to define approaches to the software development lifecycle.

As far as I have been concerned, waterfall and agile are not methodologies, they are vaguely defined approaches/models. The definition of a methodology being a set of tools and techniques used to exactly define the steps taken to develop a successful software project.

In my understanding, the following statements are true: -

- SSADM (Structured System Analysis and Design) is a waterfall
  methodology
- Scrum is an agile methodology
- XP is an agile methodology

Thus, it would not make sense to write: -

- Waterfall is a waterfall methodology
- Agile is an agile methodology

Since you would get into a recursive mess.

The issue is, whenever I get into this debate with anyone, they seem to be certain that waterfall is a methodology and so is agile.

An example of what I see as being incorrect is the following article: -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_methodology

> Methodologies
>   Waterfall Prototype model Incremental Iterative V-Model Spiral Scrum Cleanroom RAD DSDM RUP XP Agile Lean Dual Vee Model TDD FDD DDD

These are listed as methodologies on the wikipedia page and I find that this is just plain wrong. Can someone please correct me and/or let me know what terminology I should be using?

Comment: A programmer once said that waterfall is a waterfall methodology.  When they asked if waterfall methodology was named after waterfall, the programmer lapsed into a coma and has not awoken.  You're messing with dangerous forces here.

Comment: I do wish stack exchange wouldn't allow down votes without commented reasoning

Comment: In the absence of a specific comment, you might find it useful to assume that a downvote means the downvoter thought that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", since that's what the downvote button offers as a tooltip.

Comment: @AakashM: honestly, the question shows some research effort, it is IMHO very clear, and it is specific for software development. So I would be interested in the reasons for downvoting, too. But I guess this may be a good starting point for a question on meta. - Seems this question was already asked there http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/many-down-votes-without-explanation

Comment: @DocBrown sure, I was just offering OP some unsolicited advice. It's been a recurring theme on MSO since forever, pretty much.

Comment: A pedantic note: Scrum is *not* a methodology. It's a framework, upon which you can use your preferred techniques (such as agile software development practices).

Comment: @DocBrown's answer (particularly the last sentence) shows that this question is not about programming but about language semantics. The question is also overly verbose and could be phrased more succinctly.

Comment: @DaveHillier: IMHO a question about language semantics can also be a programming question. And I don't think this question is phrased so badly that it deserves do many downvotes.

Comment: @DocBrown, then why dont you up-vote it? people get way to hung up on votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call "Waterfall" a methodology, or if you only call something like SSADM a methodology, depends mainly on the level of detail and the context of your discussion. Same holds for "Agile" (though I guess the latter term is not very often considered to be a methodology on its own).

So my advice is: whenever you want to talk about those things, just clarify the context before you run into a fruitless debate.

Natural language is not always precise.